# Heatmap formatting in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following code to plot each array in an n-dim array as one
row in a color-coded plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(new_var, cmap='hot')
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(80, 60), dpi=80)
plt.show()
```

This is quite straightforward, but I can't change the formating of the figure, and right
now it is squeezed like this:

[image]

How can the formatting be adjusted?

Here the [link to the underlying npy data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/48m4v06ndrvay2k/new_var.npy?dl=0)

Comment: have you tried `rcParams` like `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,3)`